# why use netty loop writeAndFlush to send DatagramPacket must sleep the thread for a while?

Tags: java, udp, netty, udpclient

There is a problem that has been confusing me for a long time.
that is when i use netty loop writeAndFlush to send DatagramPacket to my udp server, there are most messages are lost.
but if i sleep the thread for a while, all the messages will be delivered.
like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    int count = 3000;
    AtomicInteger integer = new AtomicInteger(count);
    AtomicInteger countInteger = new AtomicInteger();
    Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    ChannelFuture channelFuture = bootstrap.group(group)
            .channel(NioDatagramChannel.class)
            .option(ChannelOption.SO_BROADCAST, true)
            .option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
            .option(ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF, 1024 * 1024)
            .option(ChannelOption.SO_SNDBUF, 1024 * 1024)
            .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 3000)
            .handler(new ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {

                @Override
                protected void initChannel(Channel ch) throws Exception {
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new WakeupMessageEncoder())
                            .addLast(new WakeupMessageReplyDecoder())
                            .addLast(new SimpleChannelInboundHandler<WakeupMessageReply>() {

                                @Override
                                protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, WakeupMessageReply reply) throws Exception {
                                    countInteger.getAndIncrement();
                                    System.out.println(reply);
                                }
                            })
                            ;
                }
            }).bind(0).sync();
    Channel channel = channelFuture.channel();
    long s = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        //TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.sleep(1);
        WakeupMessage message = new WakeupMessage(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "192.168.0.3:12000", "89860918700328360182", "test message" + i);
        channel.writeAndFlush(message).addListener(f -> integer.decrementAndGet());
    }
    while (true) {
        if (integer.get() <= 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    try {
        channel.closeFuture();
        System.out.println("done：" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - s) + "ms");
        System.out.println(countInteger);
    }finally {
        group.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

i send 3000 messages,but only received little... 
like this:
[1744 messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrcqk.jpg)
but if i sleep the thread like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.sleep(1);
    WakeupMessage message = new WakeupMessage(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "192.168.0.3:12000", "89860918700328360182", "test message" + i);
    channel.writeAndFlush(message).addListener(f -> integer.decrementAndGet());
}
```

i will receive all the replay from udp server.

so why i must sleep thread???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datagram packets (UDP) do not have guaranteed delivery and may be dropped if you send too fast. There are many possible reasons for that, in your case you are most likely filling up the send buffer or the receive buffer or both. [This](https://jvns.ca/blog/2016/08/24/find-out-where-youre-dropping-packets/) article goes into more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to `sync()` the listener when you write and flush, i.e.

```
channel.writeAndFlush(message).addListener(f -> integer.decrementAndGet()).sync();
```

In my testing, this gets all 3000 responses with much lower elapsed time than sleeping. For a local UDP echo server on my laptop:

- Total Elapsed with Sleep: 3,758ms
- Total Elapsed with sync: 407ms

However, as noted by @ewramner, neither option *guarantees* you will get all 3000 responses.